# how to save file in localStorage and later on send it on server in mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

How do we save file in localStorage and later on retrive it and send it on server to save it.

```
<input id="File1" type="file" onchange="saveLocal();" />
<button type="button" onclick="saveServer()">Sync</button>
<script>
    function saveServer()
    {
        var blob = localStorage.getItem("file");
        var form = new FormData();
        form.append("file", blob);
        AjaxPost("/Grades/test", form, function (data) {
            alert(data);
        });
    }
    function saveLocal()
    {
        var file = $("#File1")[0].files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            localStorage.setItem("file", reader.result);
            $("#File1").val("");
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
</script>
```

and server side code is

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult test(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

when i issue a request file is null how we do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use jquery [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and set `contentType` option to false, forcing jQuery not to add a `Content-Type` header for you, otherwise, the boundary string will be missing from it.

`processData` need to set false too.

> By default, data passed in to the data option as an object (technically, anything other than a string) will be processed and transformed into a query string, fitting to the default content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". If you want to send a DOMDocument, or other non-processed data, set this option to false.

```
function saveServer()
{
    var blob = localStorage.getItem("file");
    var form = new FormData();
    form.append("file", blob);

    $.ajax({
    url: '/Grades/test', //full url 
    data: form,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: false, 
    processData: false,
    success:function(data) {
      alert(data);
    } 
    });

}
function saveLocal()
{
    var file = $("#File1")[0].files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        localStorage.setItem("file", reader.result);
        $("#File1").val("");
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

Comment: AjaxPost is a function that internally implement ajax and already set
contentType: false, 
processData: false,

Comment: file storing in localStorage is ok
but when receiving on server side is null.?